# mod_rewrite with url variables

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to convert the following:

http://example.com/gallery?page=1 to http://example.com/gallery/2 (without extension)

or

http://example.com/gallery.php?page=1 to http://example.com/gallery/2 (with `.php` extension)

I already have my code written to remove url extensions, but I can't seem to figure this out.

I've tried the following:

```bsh
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+)/?$ gallery.php?page=$1
```

```bsh
RewriteRule ^gallery/page/([0-9])[/]?$ gallery.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^gallery/page/([0-9])[/]?$ gallery?page=$1
```

```bsh
RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)/?$ gallery.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)/?$ gallery?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

None of these have worked.

I've read that the `L` tells the script to stop if it works, do I need to remove the `L` from everything except for the last line in a `.htaccess` file?

Here is my full `.htaccess` as of now:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*?/+)index\.php(?:/(.*))?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [L,R]

# internally add index.php to all URIs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule !^index\.php index\.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*?/+)index(?:/(.*))?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [L,R]

# internally add index to all URIs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule !^index index%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteRule    ^gallery/([0-9]+)/?$    gallery.php?page=$1    [NC]    # Handle gallery requests
RewriteRule    ^gallery/([0-9]+)/?$    gallery?page=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle gallery requests

ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error.php
```

Comment: https://www.godaddy.com/help/working-with-error-logs-1197

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642858/mod-rewrite-remove-variable-giving-500-internal-server-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be your full .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error.php

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /gallery\.php\?page=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /gallery/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+)/?$ gallery.php?page=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule !^index\.php/ index\.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

1. Ordering of your rules is important in htaccess
2. `MultiViews` need to be turned off
3. `index.php` rules should be last one as that one is handling all non-files/non-directories.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /gallery\.php\?page=([^\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ gallery/%1? [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+)/?$ gallery.php?page=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error, and I can't locate the error log. I'm using Godaddy as a host.